# How do i add the master repo version of cloud_firestore plugin (inside flutterfire package) to my app's pubspec.yaml?

Tags: git, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, dart-pub

I need the disableNetwork() feature of cloud firestore in my flutter app. It is not available in the latest version (0.13.7) of [cloud_firestore](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore) . It is available in the master repo of the git hub repository. I could not add the git link which directs to the [cloud_firestore](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/tree/master/packages/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore) package because it is inside the repository [flutterfire](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire) . So, how do i add it in my pubspec.yaml file.

```
  cloud_firestore: 
     git: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire.git
```

Comment: Pre-release version has now also been published. Thanks

Comment: That is so great .. thanks for the info !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `path` option as described [here](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#git-packages).

For example:

```
dependencies:
  kittens:
    git:
      url: git@github.com:munificent/cats.git
      path: path/to/kittens
```